# Post Title and Info not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, title, genesis, accessible

I am developing a WordPress accessible website on Genesis! I have installed the WordPress Genesis Accessible plugin and I have customized the Leiden Child theme that you can get [here](http://genesis-accessible.org/).

On the functions.php page I have also added this code to it...

```
//* Customize the entry meta in the entry header (requires HTML5 theme support)
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'sp_post_info_filter' );
function sp_post_info_filter($post_info) {
    $post_info = '[post_date] by [post_author_posts_link] [post_comments] [post_edit]';
    return $post_info;
}
```

However on all of the blog posts none of the titles or author info is showing up! If you wish to view the site's posts page you can do so [HERE](http://nfbuk.brumdesign.uk/posts/).

Thanks in advance for any help.
- Phillip

Answer (score 1):

Doh!

Found out that I added a display:none; on the entry titles in the main css! Was trying to remove the titles from the pages is all!

Quite simple really!